# How to create an array of binary literals

Tags: c++

I want an array of binary messages in my code as literals.  The messages are quite smal so I thought it would be easiest to use 'binary' literals.  But how to do it?

I tried this code:

```
struct binary_message
{
    binary_message(int size, unsigned char* bytes) : size_(size), bytes_(bytes) {}
    int size_;
    unsigned char* bytes_;
};

binary_message messages[] = {
    { 3, { 0x1, 0x2, 0x3 } },
    { 2, { 0x1, 0x2 } },
    { 1, { 0x1 } }
};
```

with the Visual Studio 2013 C++ compiler I get error:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'initializer-list' to 'binary_message'. No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

With g++ I get:

```
>g++ main.cpp
main.cpp:13:1: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
main.cpp:13:1: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
main.cpp:13:1: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
main.cpp:13:1: error: could not convert '{3, {1, 2, 3}}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'binary_message'
main.cpp:13:1: error: could not convert '{2, {1, 2}}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'binary_message'
main.cpp:13:1: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'unsigned char*' [-fpermissive]
main.cpp:4:2: error:   initializing argument 2 of 'binary_message::binary_message(int, unsigned char*)' [-fpermissive]
```

if I use g++ -std=c++0x main.cpp I still get:

```
main.cpp:13:1: error: could not convert '{3, {1, 2, 3}}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'binary_message'
main.cpp:13:1: error: could not convert '{2, {1, 2}}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'binary_message'
main.cpp:13:1: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'unsigned char*' [-fpermissive]
main.cpp:4:2: error:   initializing argument 2 of 'binary_message::binary_message(int, unsigned char*)' [-fpermissive]
```

How do I fix this?

UPDATE

I guess you mean something like this?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct binary_message
{
    binary_message(std::initializer_list<unsigned char> data) : bytes_(data) {}
    std::vector<unsigned char> bytes_;
};

int main()
{
    binary_message messages[] = {
            { 0x1, 0x2, 0x3 },
            { 0x1, 0x2 },
            { 0x1 }
    };

    binary_message msg1 = messages[0];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Binary literals are an actual thing with C++14 and look like `0b100110` - if that isn't what you mean you should maybe clarify what you want to do.

Comment: You're using a combination of decimal literals (like "3") and hexadecimal literals (like "0x3").  But whether you represent those integer values as decimal, hex, octal, binary, or whatever, they're still just numbers to the compiler.  There's no optimization at runtime that corresponds to that representation.

Comment: With `const`, you may do something like `"\x01\x02\x03"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an initializer-list constructor if you want to use initializer lists to construct your object. Your current constructor accepts size of buffer and the buffer, but `{ 3, { 0x1, 0x2, 0x3 } }` is nothing like that - it is an initializer list of a number and initializer list.

To properly use initializer lists, your class and constructor should be looking approximately following:

```
binary_message( std::initializer_list<int> data) : data(data) {}
...
std::vector<int> data;
```

And you would not use `size` at all - the size of vector would tell you.